# Google Sign Sign On without Owin Is this possible in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-oauth

I am using **MVC** 5 for my shopping Cart Application. I want to add single sign on with google and Facebook.

But i didn't want **Owin** . How i can do this ?

**Especially i need any .net Library.**

Comment: This link here: http://www.codedigest.com/posts/13/integrate-google-gmail-authentication-in-aspnet-mvc-50---oauth-20

Comment: I am facing this problem => For using Above link =>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)